# Old Movie with Man Put on Lookout Edge to Die

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember seeing an old sci-fi movie where there was a scene on a boat. The guy is tortured by putting him up on the lookout ledge. Then a storm comes and the guy is continuously struck by lightning until only his skeleton is left when they take the body down.

i can't remember the specifics of the sci-fi movie but I think in that scene it was a scientist that was persecuted aboard the ship for some reason.

I think the people and the ship was late 1700's or 1800s style.

Comment: What is "sci-fi" about it?

Comment: i just remember that it was in a sci-fi movie but i can't remember which one.

Comment: Was it a private ship or a naval vessel? Was the protagonist young or old? Do you actually see him struck by lightning? When you say "old sci-fi movie", was it black and white or colour? Do you remember why he was punished? Why were they on a boat?

Comment: i think it was a naval ship, not a private one. full crew and they were nervous,i think, as they watched the storm. from what i remember, you see the body from far away, from the deck so you're not quite sure what happens to him until they bring the skeleton down. i think it may have been color, but i'm not 100% sure. i don't remember why he was being punished -  it may be that the man who killed him wasn't from the boat and neither was he and that the boat was incidental to them both

Comment: I didn't ask you for the name of the movie, I asked you **what was sci-fi about it**. Did it have invading aliens? Monsters? Robots? Zombies? Time machines? Spaceships? Colliding planets? Atomigeddon? Invisibility? Dragons? Demons? Angels? Ghosts?

Comment: i don't remember anything really about the movie other than that one scene but i remember if being a sci-fi movie. i've been looking for it for a while.

Comment: Sounds a little Sinbad-ish, maybe?

Comment: i think it was much later time period than that. maybe 1700's - 1800's? it was also pretty realistic in the scene that i remember.

Comment: @user43003 now that is the kind of info you should put in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bit of a long shot, but towards the end of the film [Frankenstein: The True Story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankenstein:_The_True_Story) Frankenstein is on a boat from England to America. The monster has stowed away on the boat and when he (it?) emerges a big fight ensues. Polidori is hoisted into the rigging where he is struck by lightning leaving just a skeleton.

The scientist would presumably be Victor Frankenstein.

Comment: I'll second this. James Mason hanging from the mast. I'm old enough to have watched it when it first aired.

Comment: @Fruitbat: me too :-) It was the sort of scene that stays with you, especially since I was only 12 at the time!!

Comment: just watched the scene. it seems a lot different than my child's memories of it but it must be the same one i'm thinking of. the people and the ship seem to be the same. i don't remember the monster being up there with him though. will chock it up to a 30+ year old memory.  thanks again